# How to add # (fragment identifier) to Wordpress URL and use AJAX/JS to load content on that page?

Tags: javascript, ajax, wordpress

I'm new to coding so please bear with me.

I'm looking to create a Wordpress page with many different translation versions, for example, **www.example.com/#japanese**, **www.example.com/#german** etc. I understand that anything after # sign will not be indexed by Google, so Google will only see **www.example.com**, which is precisely what I want.

The thing is, I don't want to have to create sections and links to the translated pages from the homepage **www.example.com**. I want to keep it clean, so that the translated pages can only be seen and read by human readers, when I share the exact link with them (**www.example.com/#japanese**).

From what I've gathered online, it seems like there's a way to do this with AJAX/JS but the only coding knowledge I have (if you'd even call it that) is HTML and Wordpress. I'd really appreciate it if someone just provide me with a detailed explanation on how to go about doing this using the example URLs above with AJAX/JS. From scratch would be good. Like, how to add the # sign to a Wordpress post/page URL (I can't even get this part right lol), and how to incorporate AJAX/JS to load the translated pages (do you even need this?).

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

I see the idea of making it user friendly but why would you go through the hassle of translating the site and not utilize its full potential?

In other words, it might be more beneficial to create a static URL for each language version. In fact, if you can put them all in a sub-folder structure such as example.com/japanese/ it would allow you to do international SEO and get more traffic from that specific language.

With this structure, you just need to have the translated pages in separate folders and have clear navigation icons on each page to let the users know there are different version of the page in different languages.

In case if your aim is to target a set of countries, you might want to use localized top level domain such as .jp
It will make the international SEO efforts much easier. It would also mean you need to create a separate Wordpress site for each country though.

There are many useful international SEO posts/ articles out there so perhaps do a bit of research before settle to an approach. Doing a quick search on Moz.com forum might help.